# Rewrite php file to a folder instead of using a folder called /about

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My url right now is:

```
localhost/about/index.php
```

Result wanted:
`localhost/about.php` But I want it to appear as `localhost/about/` without having to place it into an about folder.

I'm quite inexperienced on how you would do this with a `.htaccess` file.

### I found this idea online, but mine isn't using a database:

Example 3: The site has an unwieldy URL. How to clean it up
This sort of situation can arise when URLs are long and complex.

Take the URL below as an example:

```
http://example.com/results.php?products=produce&type=fruit&species=apple
```

As effective as the URL is in delivering the correct content, it is not very memorable for the consumer. URL rewrites would allow you to convert the URL to something simpler and clearer:

```
http://example.com/produce/fruit/apple
```

In order to accomplish this, we would need the following lines in our `.htaccess` file (you can add as many section as needed in the `.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(meat|produce|dairy)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ results.php?products=$1&type=$2&species=$3
```

Now for an explanation:

First the `^(caret)` starts the expression.

`(meat|produce|dairy)`: If we want to limit the options that can be typed in, we can specify the only values we will accept: in this case the variety of groceries. If anything besides one of those three 3 keywords is typed in, the URL rewrite will not take place.

The `([^/.]+)` indicates that anything can be written between the forward slash besides the characters following the caret, in this case, the forward slash or period.

`results.php?products=$1&type=$2&species=$3`: Each value in the parentheses will be extracted and then applied to the longer URL in the substitution part of the expression. `$1` indicates the first parantheses, `$2`, the second, `$3`, the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the .php from the URL you can use this...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

just save it as a file name .htaccess in the root of your application.

This will allow you to use `localhost/about` as well as `localhost/about.php` both are valid.

Comment: Thanks, would this affect localhost? It seems like I get an internet Internal error if I'm using localhost. I'm guessing if it's live it would work?

Comment: What are you using to run localhost? MAMP? WAMP? LAMP?

Comment: For now I removed the .htaccess file to another folder for now. I was having issuses with folders accessing the css file. So this solution hopefully will work. Does WAMP prevent me from seeing this?

Comment: You will be able to use it on localhost if done right. You will have to edit this file C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/conf/extra/httpd-default.conf. by changing everywhere that says "AllowOverride None" to say "AllowOverride All" and restart WAMP

Comment: I couldn't find that option, but thanks though. Once I put the website in a live direcotry I'll do tests and come back to this post for review.

Comment: I have a newer version of Apache running.